# Red5 1.0 does not always send the duration of the video

Tags: video, stream, red5, duration

I've created a Red5-based video recorder/streamer and the problem is if I play back a previously recorded video the duration of the stream does not always got by the client. I think the server does not sends it reliably... Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To get the current runtime of a playback video you simply call:

```
this._ns.time
```

_ns is a flash.net.NetStream method, see:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#time

sorry I can't say anything about getting the total duration of the video, we have this information already from somewhere else...

Sebastian

Comment: I use NetStream.time to get the current playhead time. There is an event called onMetaData that includes the duration and I use it to set the max value of the slider. But it seems to me the onMetaData is not always called. :S

Comment: where are you listening for onMetaData on NetStream or on NetConnection? I think both is possible but has different events.

Comment: Also I think there is a possibility to actively ask for the total duration of a video.

Comment: I'm listening for onMetaData on NetStream. How to get the duration the other way?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not alone with this issue, there are workarounds and I found one that always works.

```
NetConnection.call("getStreamLength", Responder, stream)
```

Using this I always get the length of the stream. I call it right after `NetStream.play(stream)`.

Comment: yes, that might be the "active method" that I was refering to :)